# Single servlet for application

Tags: java

Is it possible to have an application such as shopping cart, to have a single servlet in the entire application, which will result into a single entry in web.xml? If yes, how?

Comment: Not specific question. What do you want ? What have you tried ?

Comment: i have been told to implement ESCALATION TRACKING SYSTEM with just one front end servlet(no other servlet allowed), which will result into a single entry in web.xml.Is that possible?if yes then how?

Comment: You can implement your own MVC framework with single `Servlet` acting as `FrontController`

Answer (score 0):

Sure. There are in fact several webapp frameworks (e.g. Struts and JSF) based on a single servlet that dispatches incoming requests to application-specific controller classes after mapping URL components to controllers and parameters.

Comment: well, I am aware about struts and jsf but im not allowed to use it.apart from MVC framework im not allowed to use any framework

Comment: well im sorry if my earlier statement has caused some confusion.Let me put it again. Im required to use MVC pattern, but no framework like struts.

Comment: @milind: My point is that those two frameworks do it like that, so it's obviously possible, and you could take a look at their sourcecode (FacesServlet, StrutsServlet) to see how it's done.